# Json response jquery_callback({'json":"data")

Tags: jquery, json, callback, response

Very quick question. How to create json response in php,laravel to have something like this?

```
jQuery111106639087000054806_1462918208435([{"TaskID":121,"OwnerID":1
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

->setCallback() solved my question.